# Message splitting in Camel

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I am trying to write a camel route which would send different elements of a list to different queues.

The message body would be a list with 2 xml's. For example:

```
<Cat>
<Name>Cat1</Name>
</Cat>,
<Dog>
<Name>Dog1</Name>
</Dog>
```

Now, I need to send the 'Cat' part of the message i.e. Cat1 part to queue1 and the 'Dog' part of xml i.e. Dog1 to a different queue?

This is the route that I have, but is not working:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:InQueue" />        
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${in.body} regex 'Cat'</simple>
            <to uri="jms:queue:CatQueue" />
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${in.body} regex 'Dog'</simple>
            <to uri="jms:queue:DogQueue" />
        </when>
    </choice>
</route>
```

Any ideas on what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to split the list using the `,` token. Second, you have to parse the XML parts using XPath expressions and send the messages to the appropriate JMS queues:

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:InQueue" />
    <split>
        <tokenize token=","/>
        <log message="Working on split: ${body}" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <xpath>/Cat</xpath>
                <to uri="jms:queue:CatQueue" />
            </when>
            <when>
                <xpath>/Dog</xpath>
                <to uri="jms:queue:DogQueue" />
            </when>
        </choice>
    </split>
</route>
```

Comment: The 'Cat' xml gets routed to cat queue correctly. But the Dog xml is not being routed at all...Its just routing the first element in the list(i.e. cat) and then returning...does not bother about second element(dog) at all..

Comment: I used `<Cat><Name>Cat1</Name></Cat>,<Dog><Name>Dog1</Name></Dog>` as input string and everything worked as expected. Did you see following output in your logs: `Working on split: <Cat><Name>Cat1</Name></Cat>` and `Working on split: <Dog><Name>Dog1</Name></Dog>`?

Comment: My Bad...I saw it wrong...It worked...Thanks...But how about if there are namespaces in the xmls..What do I have to change to account for namespaces...for example:<Cat xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:lw="http://www.org/oagis/9">
    <name>Cat1</name>
</Cat>,
<Dog xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:lw="http://www.org/oagis/9">
    <name>Dog1</name>
</Dog>

Comment: Got it...using '/*[local-name()='Cat']' in xpath for '/Cat' worked...Thanks again